# Retrieve letter value (defined by scheme) for a particular student/grade item through Valence?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I have a select box with letter grade values with a custom grade scheme tied to the select box. The select box is setup as a "bonus" item, so the point value doesn't have any impact on any in-course calculations, but I do have to assign an out of value for the item. A user (faculty) picks a grade from the scheme (A, B, etc.) drop down. If I work my way down to retrieve the grade selected for a particular student, I get a point value for the "DisplayedGrade" attribute, but that point value IS NOT what's actually displayed. For example, A was selected. The "DisplayedGrade" comes back as "9.4/10". I guess I can figure out a way to translate those point values to letters, but I want the letter selected. Is there some way to get the actual letter value? Do I have to mix in the scheme somehow, or is my only path to do a translation of the score to a separate reference of point value to letter, and make sure people setup the grade item the exact same way every time?

UPDATE: Since I first typed this up I've come to realize that the 'point' value assigned is actually the % value I had to enter in when creating the initial "Assigned Value %" in the scheme settings. In this case 9.4 === "A" that was selected. In the scheme, 94% was the value entered for A in the Assigned Value %.

UPDATE^2: Examples Help!

Here's the call I ran: /d2l/api/le/1.1/184115/grades/3502480/values/180070

Based off of http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#get--d2l-api-le-(D2LVERSION-version)-(D2LID-orgUnitId)-grades-final-values-(D2LID-userId)

This is what was returned.

```
{
    "GradeObjectIdentifier": "3502480",
    "GradeObjectName": "eGrade",
    "GradeObjectType": 3,
    "GradeObjectTypeName": "Selectbox",
    "DisplayedGrade": "9.4 / 10"
}
```

This is what I had *hoped* to get:

```
{
    "GradeObjectIdentifier": "3502480",
    "GradeObjectName": "eGrade",
    "GradeObjectType": 3,
    "GradeObjectTypeName": "Selectbox",
    "DisplayedGrade": "A"
}
```

I'm thinking I'll have to call up the scheme as well to compare values.

Comment: I see you're using v1.1 of the LE APIs: can you please let us know what the product version of the back-end LMS is?

Comment: v10.0 at present. The last I heard we *might* upgrade to 10.2 (or whatever it is, we're apparently skipping 10.1) this spring sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this on two test LMS instances: one LE v10.0.0 and one LE v10.2.0. In both cases, I was able to get a returned grade value block showing a `DisplayedGrade` with the *symbol* showing, and not the numeric value as you have. I used the routes `/d2l/api/le/1.1/{orgUnitId}/grades/values/{userId}/` (with an administrator calling user context) and `/d2l/api/le/1.1/{orgUnitId}/grades/values/myGradeValues/` (with a student calling user context).

I think the difficulty for you may be with the grade object definition itself. In order to show the *grade scheme symbol* instead of the points value you need to

1. Edit the grade object.
2. In the 'Display Options' section for the *Student View*, select *Override display options for this item*.
3. Ensure that *Grade scheme symbol* is checked.

It appears that as long as *Grade scheme symbol* is checked, the API call seems to return the appropriate symbol as the `DisplayedGrade` property (even if *Points Grade* is also checked). The default display setting seems to be to have only *Points Grade* selected (at least on my test instances).

Comment: I'll need to try this out. I thought I played around with the display settings, but I probably need to take a closer look.

Comment: I played around with this a little more and I think the Override settings on the *Grade Item* don't actually come to bear (unfortunately?) in this context. I had played around with it before, and did so again, the settings on the *item* didn't have an effect so I wondered if there were overarching gradebook settings that might apply. Under Grades > Org Unit Display Options > Student View Display Options > Grade Details, *Grade Scheme Symbol* needed to be checked. Once checked, the symbol came through.

Comment: Looking into this some more I'm not sure I like how this pans out. If I modify the org unit display options for the student view it, obviously, ends up having an impact on how *all* the grades are displayed in the course (to the student), not just the measly single grade book item that I want to try and pull out.

I should have said too earlier, _thanks(!)_ for the suggestion. Even though it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it got me looking at the settings again.

Comment: I agree with your point as does our product team; there is a enhancement request on the roadmap to retrieve relevant grade schema information with a grade value call, so that you'd get the value, the symbol, and perhaps colour information all in the one call. This would let callers that have permission to look at grades get this information (for display purposes) without necessarily having the right to look at the entire grade schema objects.